# Hybridauth returns empty user contacts list for google+

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-plus, hybridauth

I've successfully setup a Hybridauth web app to obtain the users contacts from a number of different providers. The only provider I seem to have a problem with is Google, which would simply return no contacts for any user - except myself. I've tried my luck with access_type on- and offline and with both approval_prompt "force" and "auto" and various scopes. I am currently not storing the tokens. What baffles me is that it works if i am the user, but not for anyone else. This is the log of such a session that fails to download users (I removed tokens and secrets) even though the requesting user does have some:

```
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::initialize()
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). PHP version: 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.26
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth version: 2.1.2
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth called from: https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/download.php?Providers=Google&UserKey=
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- PHP open_basedir is on. http://php.net/open-basedir.
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump used config:  -- (skipped, contains secrets)
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump current session:  -- 
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize: check if any error is stored on the endpoint...
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize: no error found. initialization succeed.
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::authenticate( Google )
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::authenticate( Google ), User not connected to the provider. Try to authenticate..
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::setup( Google ) -- 
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::setup( Google ), no params given. Trying to get the sotred for this provider. -- 
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::setup( Google ), no stored params found for this provider. Initialize a new one for new session
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::setup( Google ). HybridAuth Callback URL set to:  -- https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/download.php?Providers=Google&UserKey=
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Provider_Adapter::factory( Google )
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Provider_Model::__construct( Google ) initialized. dump current adapter instance:  -- O:23:"Hybrid_Providers_Google":7:{s:5:"scope";s:122:"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";s:10:"providerId";s:6:"Google";s:6:"config";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:39:"AppId";s:6:"secret";s:24:"mySecret";}}s:6:"params";a:1:{s:15:"hauth_return_to";s:109:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/download.php?Providers=Google&UserKey=";}s:8:"endpoint";N;s:4:"user";O:11:"Hybrid_User":3:{s:10:"providerId";s:6:"Google";s:9:"timestamp";i:1407231094;s:7:"profile";O:19:"Hybrid_User_Profile":22:{s:10:"identifier";N;s:10:"webSiteURL";N;s:10:"profileURL";N;s:8:"photoURL";N;s:11:"displayName";N;s:11:"description";N;s:9:"firstName";N;s:8:"lastName";N;s:6:"gender";N;s:8:"language";N;s:3:"age";N;s:8:"birthDay";N;s:10:"birthMonth";N;s:9:"birthYear";N;s:5:"email";N;s:13:"emailVerified";N;s:5:"phone";N;s:7:"address";N;s:7:"country";N;s:6:"region";N;s:4:"city";N;s:3:"zip";N;}}s:3:"api";O:12:"OAuth2Client":22:{s:12:"api_base_url";s:0:"";s:13:"authorize_url";s:41:"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";s:9:"token_url";s:42:"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";s:14:"token_info_url";s:46:"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo";s:9:"client_id";s:39:"AppId";s:13:"client_secret";s:24:"mySecret";s:12:"redirect_uri";N;s:12:"access_token";s:0:"";s:13:"refresh_token";s:0:"";s:23:"access_token_expires_in";s:0:"";s:23:"access_token_expires_at";s:0:"";s:15:"sign_token_name";s:12:"access_token";s:11:"decode_json";b:1;s:13:"curl_time_out";i:30;s:21:"curl_connect_time_out";i:30;s:19:"curl_ssl_verifypeer";b:0;s:11:"curl_header";a:0:{}s:14:"curl_useragent";s:77:"OAuth/2 Simple PHP Client v0.1; HybridAuth http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/";s:24:"curl_authenticate_method";s:4:"POST";s:10:"curl_proxy";N;s:9:"http_code";s:0:"";s:9:"http_info";s:0:"";}}
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Provider_Adapter::login( Google ) 
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Enter [Google]::logout()
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Provider_Adapter::login( Google ), redirect the user to login_start URL. -- 
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::redirect( https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Google&hauth.time=1407231094, PHP )

INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::initialize()
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). PHP version: 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.26
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth version: 2.1.2
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth called from: https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Google&hauth.time=1407231094
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- PHP open_basedir is on. http://php.net/open-basedir.
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump used config:  -- (skipped)
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump current session:  -- a:3:{s:36:"hauth_session.google.hauth_return_to";s:118:"s:109:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/download.php?Providers=Google&UserKey=";";s:35:"hauth_session.google.hauth_endpoint";s:97:"s:89:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Google";";s:39:"hauth_session.google.id_provider_params";s:486:"a:5:{s:15:"hauth_return_to";s:109:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/download.php?Providers=Google&UserKey=";s:11:"hauth_token";s:26:"pvhj5g2q9vko1io5osnvgmsv42";s:10:"hauth_time";i:1407231094;s:11:"login_start";s:112:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Google&hauth.time=1407231094";s:10:"login_done";s:89:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Google";}";}
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize: check if any error is stored on the endpoint...
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize: no error found. initialization succeed.
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::setup( Google ) -- 
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::setup( Google ), no params given. Trying to get the sotred for this provider. -- Array
(
    [hauth_return_to] => https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/download.php?Providers=Google&UserKey=
    [hauth_token] => sometoken
    [hauth_time] => 1407231094
    [login_start] => https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Google&hauth.time=1407231094
    [login_done] => https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Google
)

DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::setup( Google ). HybridAuth Callback URL set to:  -- https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/download.php?Providers=Google&UserKey=
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Provider_Adapter::factory( Google )
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Provider_Model::__construct( Google ) initialized. dump current adapter instance:  -- O:23:"Hybrid_Providers_Google":7:{s:5:"scope";s:122:"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";s:10:"providerId";s:6:"Google";s:6:"config";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:39:"AppId";s:6:"secret";s:24:"mySecret";}}s:6:"params";a:5:{s:15:"hauth_return_to";s:109:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/download.php?Providers=Google&UserKey=";s:11:"hauth_token";s:26:"pvhj5g2q9vko1io5osnvgmsv42";s:10:"hauth_time";i:1407231094;s:11:"login_start";s:112:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Google&hauth.time=1407231094";s:10:"login_done";s:89:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Google";}s:8:"endpoint";s:89:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Google";s:4:"user";O:11:"Hybrid_User":3:{s:10:"providerId";s:6:"Google";s:9:"timestamp";i:1407231094;s:7:"profile";O:19:"Hybrid_User_Profile":22:{s:10:"identifier";N;s:10:"webSiteURL";N;s:10:"profileURL";N;s:8:"photoURL";N;s:11:"displayName";N;s:11:"description";N;s:9:"firstName";N;s:8:"lastName";N;s:6:"gender";N;s:8:"language";N;s:3:"age";N;s:8:"birthDay";N;s:10:"birthMonth";N;s:9:"birthYear";N;s:5:"email";N;s:13:"emailVerified";N;s:5:"phone";N;s:7:"address";N;s:7:"country";N;s:6:"region";N;s:4:"city";N;s:3:"zip";N;}}s:3:"api";O:12:"OAuth2Client":22:{s:12:"api_base_url";s:0:"";s:13:"authorize_url";s:41:"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";s:9:"token_url";s:42:"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";s:14:"token_info_url";s:46:"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo";s:9:"client_id";s:39:"AppId";s:13:"client_secret";s:24:"mySecret";s:12:"redirect_uri";s:89:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Google";s:12:"access_token";s:0:"";s:13:"refresh_token";s:0:"";s:23:"access_token_expires_in";s:0:"";s:23:"access_token_expires_at";s:0:"";s:15:"sign_token_name";s:12:"access_token";s:11:"decode_json";b:1;s:13:"curl_time_out";i:30;s:21:"curl_connect_time_out";i:30;s:19:"curl_ssl_verifypeer";b:0;s:11:"curl_header";a:0:{}s:14:"curl_useragent";s:77:"OAuth/2 Simple PHP Client v0.1; HybridAuth http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/";s:24:"curl_authenticate_method";s:4:"POST";s:10:"curl_proxy";N;s:9:"http_code";s:0:"";s:9:"http_info";s:0:"";}}
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Endpoint: call adapter [Google] loginBegin()
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::redirect( https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=AppId&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myDomain.de%2Fservices%2Foauth%2Fhybridauth-master%2Fhybridauth%2F%3Fhauth.done%3DGoogle&response_type=code&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fplus.login+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fm8%2Ffeeds%2F&access_type=offline, PHP )

INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::initialize()
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). PHP version: 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.26
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth version: 2.1.2
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth called from: https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Google&code=4/3In7HXd4KT5XobwEuVvwdxLFr14d.YlKx6mGIylUSYFZr95uygvVLhghLjwI&authuser=0&num_sessions=1&session_state=0cd3633d00ec098f087e6e3ab876975b4e235f16..6880&prompt=none
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- PHP open_basedir is on. http://php.net/open-basedir.
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump used config:  -- skipped
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump current session:  -- a:3:{s:36:"hauth_session.google.hauth_return_to";s:118:"s:109:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/download.php?Providers=Google&UserKey=";";s:35:"hauth_session.google.hauth_endpoint";s:97:"s:89:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Google";";s:39:"hauth_session.google.id_provider_params";s:486:"a:5:{s:15:"hauth_return_to";s:109:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/download.php?Providers=Google&UserKey=";s:11:"hauth_token";s:26:"sometoken";s:10:"hauth_time";i:1407231094;s:11:"login_start";s:112:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Google&hauth.time=1407231094";s:10:"login_done";s:89:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Google";}";}
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize: check if any error is stored on the endpoint...
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize: no error found. initialization succeed.
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::setup( Google ) -- 
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::setup( Google ), no params given. Trying to get the sotred for this provider. -- Array
(
    [hauth_return_to] => https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/download.php?Providers=Google&UserKey=
    [hauth_token] => sometoken
    [hauth_time] => 1407231094
    [login_start] => https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Google&hauth.time=1407231094
    [login_done] => https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Google
)

DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::setup( Google ). HybridAuth Callback URL set to:  -- https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/download.php?Providers=Google&UserKey=
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Provider_Adapter::factory( Google )
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Hybrid_Provider_Model::__construct( Google ) initialized. dump current adapter instance:  -- O:23:"Hybrid_Providers_Google":7:{s:5:"scope";s:122:"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";s:10:"providerId";s:6:"Google";s:6:"config";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:39:"AppId";s:6:"secret";s:24:"mySecret";}}s:6:"params";a:5:{s:15:"hauth_return_to";s:109:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/download.php?Providers=Google&UserKey=";s:11:"hauth_token";s:26:"pvhj5g2q9vko1io5osnvgmsv42";s:10:"hauth_time";i:1407231094;s:11:"login_start";s:112:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.start=Google&hauth.time=1407231094";s:10:"login_done";s:89:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Google";}s:8:"endpoint";s:89:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Google";s:4:"user";O:11:"Hybrid_User":3:{s:10:"providerId";s:6:"Google";s:9:"timestamp";i:1407231094;s:7:"profile";O:19:"Hybrid_User_Profile":22:{s:10:"identifier";N;s:10:"webSiteURL";N;s:10:"profileURL";N;s:8:"photoURL";N;s:11:"displayName";N;s:11:"description";N;s:9:"firstName";N;s:8:"lastName";N;s:6:"gender";N;s:8:"language";N;s:3:"age";N;s:8:"birthDay";N;s:10:"birthMonth";N;s:9:"birthYear";N;s:5:"email";N;s:13:"emailVerified";N;s:5:"phone";N;s:7:"address";N;s:7:"country";N;s:6:"region";N;s:4:"city";N;s:3:"zip";N;}}s:3:"api";O:12:"OAuth2Client":22:{s:12:"api_base_url";s:0:"";s:13:"authorize_url";s:41:"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";s:9:"token_url";s:42:"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";s:14:"token_info_url";s:46:"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo";s:9:"client_id";s:39:"AppId";s:13:"client_secret";s:24:"mySecret";s:12:"redirect_uri";s:89:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Google";s:12:"access_token";s:0:"";s:13:"refresh_token";s:0:"";s:23:"access_token_expires_in";s:0:"";s:23:"access_token_expires_at";s:0:"";s:15:"sign_token_name";s:12:"access_token";s:11:"decode_json";b:1;s:13:"curl_time_out";i:30;s:21:"curl_connect_time_out";i:30;s:19:"curl_ssl_verifypeer";b:0;s:11:"curl_header";a:0:{}s:14:"curl_useragent";s:77:"OAuth/2 Simple PHP Client v0.1; HybridAuth http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/";s:24:"curl_authenticate_method";s:4:"POST";s:10:"curl_proxy";N;s:9:"http_code";s:0:"";s:9:"http_info";s:0:"";}}
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Endpoint: call adapter [Google] loginFinish() 
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- Enter OAuth2Client::request( https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token )
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:34+02:00 -- OAuth2Client::request(). dump request params:  -- a:5:{s:9:"client_id";s:39:"AppId";s:13:"client_secret";s:24:"mySecret";s:10:"grant_type";s:18:"authorization_code";s:12:"redirect_uri";s:89:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/?hauth.done=Google";s:4:"code";s:62:"4/3In7HXd4KT5XobwEuVvwdxLFr14d.YlKx6mGIylUSYFZr95uygvVLhghLjwI";}
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- OAuth2Client::request(). dump request info:  -- a:21:{s:3:"url";s:42:"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";s:12:"content_type";s:31:"application/json; charset=utf-8";s:9:"http_code";i:200;s:11:"header_size";i:471;s:12:"request_size";i:293;s:8:"filetime";i:-1;s:17:"ssl_verify_result";i:0;s:14:"redirect_count";i:0;s:10:"total_time";d:2.232047000000000114283693619654513895511627197265625;s:15:"namelookup_time";d:0.01287899999999999982314147217721256311051547527313232421875;s:12:"connect_time";d:0.0215109999999999988717913623759159236215054988861083984375;s:16:"pretransfer_time";d:0.043635000000000000175415237890774733386933803558349609375;s:11:"size_upload";d:771;s:13:"size_download";d:813;s:14:"speed_download";d:364;s:12:"speed_upload";d:345;s:23:"download_content_length";d:-1;s:21:"upload_content_length";d:771;s:18:"starttransfer_time";d:2.043498000000000036635583455790765583515167236328125;s:13:"redirect_time";d:0;s:8:"certinfo";a:0:{}}
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- OAuth2Client::request(). dump request result:  -- s:813:"{
  "access_token" : "somevalidlookingtoken",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3598,
  "id_token" : "somevalidlookingtoken"
}";
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Enter [Google]::setUserConnected()
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Endpoint: job done. retrun to callback url.
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::redirect( https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/download.php?Providers=Google&UserKey=, PHP )

INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::initialize()
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). PHP version: 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.26
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth version: 2.1.2
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::initialize(). Hybrid_Auth called from: https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/download.php?Providers=Google&UserKey=
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- PHP open_basedir is on. http://php.net/open-basedir.
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump used config:  -- skipped
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize. dump current session:  -- a:5:{s:39:"hauth_session.google.token.access_token";s:96:"s:88:"somevalidlookingtoken";";s:40:"hauth_session.google.token.refresh_token";s:7:"s:0:"";";s:37:"hauth_session.google.token.expires_in";s:7:"i:3598;";s:37:"hauth_session.google.token.expires_at";s:13:"i:1407234694;";s:33:"hauth_session.google.is_logged_in";s:4:"i:1;";}
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize: check if any error is stored on the endpoint...
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth initialize: no error found. initialization succeed.
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::authenticate( Google )
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::authenticate( Google ), User is already connected to this provider. Return the adapter instance.
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::getAdapter( Google )
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Auth::setup( Google ) -- 
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::setup( Google ), no params given. Trying to get the sotred for this provider. -- 
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::setup( Google ), no stored params found for this provider. Initialize a new one for new session
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Hybrid_Auth::setup( Google ). HybridAuth Callback URL set to:  -- https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/download.php?Providers=Google&UserKey=
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Provider_Adapter::factory( Google )
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Hybrid_Provider_Model::__construct( Google ) initialized. dump current adapter instance:  -- O:23:"Hybrid_Providers_Google":7:{s:5:"scope";s:122:"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/";s:10:"providerId";s:6:"Google";s:6:"config";a:2:{s:7:"enabled";b:1;s:4:"keys";a:2:{s:2:"id";s:39:"AppId";s:6:"secret";s:24:"mySecret";}}s:6:"params";a:1:{s:15:"hauth_return_to";s:109:"https://www.myDomain.de/services/oauth/hybridauth-master/hybridauth/download.php?Providers=Google&UserKey=";}s:8:"endpoint";N;s:4:"user";O:11:"Hybrid_User":3:{s:10:"providerId";s:6:"Google";s:9:"timestamp";i:1407231096;s:7:"profile";O:19:"Hybrid_User_Profile":22:{s:10:"identifier";N;s:10:"webSiteURL";N;s:10:"profileURL";N;s:8:"photoURL";N;s:11:"displayName";N;s:11:"description";N;s:9:"firstName";N;s:8:"lastName";N;s:6:"gender";N;s:8:"language";N;s:3:"age";N;s:8:"birthDay";N;s:10:"birthMonth";N;s:9:"birthYear";N;s:5:"email";N;s:13:"emailVerified";N;s:5:"phone";N;s:7:"address";N;s:7:"country";N;s:6:"region";N;s:4:"city";N;s:3:"zip";N;}}s:3:"api";O:12:"OAuth2Client":22:{s:12:"api_base_url";s:0:"";s:13:"authorize_url";s:41:"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth";s:9:"token_url";s:42:"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";s:14:"token_info_url";s:46:"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo";s:9:"client_id";s:39:"AppId";s:13:"client_secret";s:24:"mySecret";s:12:"redirect_uri";N;s:12:"access_token";s:88:"somevalidlookingtoken";s:13:"refresh_token";s:0:"";s:23:"access_token_expires_in";i:3598;s:23:"access_token_expires_at";i:1407234694;s:15:"sign_token_name";s:12:"access_token";s:11:"decode_json";b:1;s:13:"curl_time_out";i:30;s:21:"curl_connect_time_out";i:30;s:19:"curl_ssl_verifypeer";b:0;s:11:"curl_header";a:0:{}s:14:"curl_useragent";s:77:"OAuth/2 Simple PHP Client v0.1; HybridAuth http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/";s:24:"curl_authenticate_method";s:4:"POST";s:10:"curl_proxy";N;s:9:"http_code";s:0:"";s:9:"http_info";s:0:"";}}
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Enter Hybrid_Provider_Adapter::getUserContacts(), Provider: Google
INFO -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- Enter OAuth2Client::request( https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?max-results=100?orderBy=alphabetical )
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- OAuth2Client::request(). dump request params:  -- a:1:{s:12:"access_token";s:88:"somevalidlookingtoken";}
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- OAuth2Client::request(). dump request info:  -- a:21:{s:3:"url";s:198:"https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/visible?max-results=100?orderBy=alphabetical&access_token= somevalidlookingtoken";s:12:"content_type";s:31:"application/json; charset=UTF-8";s:9:"http_code";i:200;s:11:"header_size";i:433;s:12:"request_size";i:319;s:8:"filetime";i:-1;s:17:"ssl_verify_result";i:0;s:14:"redirect_count";i:0;s:10:"total_time";d:0.08033099999999999962785324214564752764999866485595703125;s:15:"namelookup_time";d:0.000975999999999999979551079665185397971072234213352203369140625;s:12:"connect_time";d:0.01267500000000000050237591864288333454169332981109619140625;s:16:"pretransfer_time";d:0.039722000000000000363709062867201282642781734466552734375;s:11:"size_upload";d:0;s:13:"size_download";d:179;s:14:"speed_download";d:2228;s:12:"speed_upload";d:0;s:23:"download_content_length";d:179;s:21:"upload_content_length";d:0;s:18:"starttransfer_time";d:0.0802960000000000062581051452070823870599269866943359375;s:13:"redirect_time";d:0;s:8:"certinfo";a:0:{}}
DEBUG -- 91.64.96.68 -- 2014-08-05T11:31:36+02:00 -- OAuth2Client::request(). dump request result:  -- s:179:"{
 "kind": "plus#peopleFeed",
 "etag": "\"AtDvFRdo1nr9guODqwfbgdIwgiE/ObDqMibaPxXUs7wb-vH72G2zQbI\"",
 "title": "Google+ List of Visible People",
 "totalItems": 0,
 "items": []
}
";
```

What might be going on there?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out: The user needs to actively allow an app to access the circles in his google+-settings. It would be nice if google reported something like "couldn't access data, because user hasn't allowed access to any circles."